# Multi-threading in Qt problematic?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been learning Qt for a while and a few days ago I decided to go on multi-threading by `QThread`. I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yazMHbIew0Q&list=SP2D1942A4688E9D63&index=35&feature=plpp_video) person. Since he says that subclassing `QThread` is not the appropriate way but by using `QObject` is. I am following his method. But he has created another class which inherits from `QObject`. I decided to make a few changes:

```
class myclass
{
private:
    dowork();

private slots:
    slota();
    slotb();
    slotc();
}

myclass::dowork()
{
    QThread lett;
    QThread latt;
    QThread pltt;
    QObject lethread;
    connect(&lett, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(slota()));
    lethread.moveToThread(&lett);
    QObject lathread;
    connect(&latt, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(slotb()));
    lathread.moveToThread(&latt);
    QObject plthread;
    connect(&pltt, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(slotc()));
    plthread.moveToThread(&pltt);

    lett.start();    
    latt.start();
    pltt.start();/*
    lett.wait();
    latt.wait();
    pltt.wait();*/
    while(lett.isRunning())
    {
        //qDebug() << "Still Running!";
    }
    lett.quit();
}
```

If I run the program it keeps running `while` loop infinitely! It doesn't come out of that at all.
I used `qdebug` inside the implementation of the 3 slots to check whether it is entering them or not, and surprisingly none of the slots gets called. Why is that so?
If I remove the comments for `.wait` then the program pauses.

What is wrong in this method? I want to avoid that extra class as my program is very small.

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to be creating plain `QObject`s, moving them to new threads, and then getting the new threads to call back to this thread's myclass.  What are the `QObject`s supposed to be doing?

Comment: @CAD_coding I don't have the time to write something extensive at this moment, but the following link explains pretty clearly why you don't want to subclass QThread, but possibly use a QObject instead: http://blog.qt.digia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: in the video tutorial mentioned above, he subclasses QObject in another class say `obj`, then he creates objects of `obj' & does what i have done. so instead of creaing an extra class, i created object of QObject.
hope i could make it clear.

Comment: @Bart ya that is why i am not subclassing QThread!

Comment: @Bart, cmannett85 i am a beginner in qt & multithreading.
so i am sorry if i made a very foolish mistake.
can you please explain what is wrong in my code?

Comment: @CAD_coding The big problem seems to be that you're not following the tutorial at all. It's not about creating plain QObject's. It's about creating your own class, which derives from QObject and has its own slots. Watch through it again and you'll see where your basis is wrong.

Comment: `I want to avoid that extra class as my program is very small`. Seriously??

Comment: You're getting the basic concept wrong. You aren't moving `myclass` objects to a thread. You're moving `QObject` objects. I suggest you carefully watch the video you pointed to again. You need to subclass `QObject`, create an instance of that subclass, connect a slot (only *one* slot) of it to the `started()` signal of a QThread instance, and then call `exec()` on the `QThread` instance.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras maybe i forgot to mention in my question, but my objective is to run dowork() in parallel with the 3 slots whose threads i have created. i dont want to move myclass to another thread. i want it to run normally along with simultaneously running the code in these 3 slots.

Comment: @CAD_coding Each QObject is tied to a single thread. You cannot have different slots of the same object run in different threads. You move the object to a thread. You don't move individual slots. If you want to run the same code in three threads, you need three objects.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras ok now i get the point.
so inevitabily i will have to create another class which inherits from QObject. create 3 slots in that class. create 3 instances of that class in my dowork(). attach a thread to each of the instances. connect started() of a thread to the corresponding slot.
am i correct?

Comment: @CAD_coding Nope. You create only one subclass with only one slot (for example, `work()`). Then you create three objects of that subclass and three QThread objects. Then you connect the `work()` slot of each object to the `QThread` object you want it to run.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras, bart thanks for your noble advice.
it helped me understand multi threading better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(lett.isRunning())
{
    //qDebug() << "Still Running!";
}
lett.quit();
```

Terribly wrong. The current thread is busy waiting and will be eating all the time. But this is not your problem. Your problem is certainly that ***the main event loop has probably not started yet***, ie you didn't do `QApplication.exec()` yet.

Qt uses events to start threads, and when you do use `movetoThread`, `start`, specific events are queued in the current thread (ie the thread executing these methods). If the main event loop has already started, then will be processed as soon as they can. But in your case I bet that you main function is :

```
 int main(){
   QApplication app();
   myclass onlyclassIwanttomake;
   onlyclassIwanttomake.dowork(); 
   app.exec(); <----HERE!!!
 }
```

The thread will be started when the main thread executes `app.exec();`. When you are busy waiting, you are preventing the main thread to process the events required to start your 
events.

EDIT: Well, another issue is that

```
lett.start();    
latt.start();
pltt.start();
```

start 3 threads which are started, and stay idle forever. They are not doing anything, but they are running (even if you remove your loop).

This is a [entry written about Qt threading](http://blog.qt.digia.com/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/). Please take the time to read it.

Comment: i have commented the lett.wait() statements. & lett.isrunning() says that it is running that thread.

Comment: & in the video he does exactly the same as i have done except for the fact that he created another class which inherited from QObject; & i created a QObject directly!

Comment: i dont get the part where you say i didnt call app.exec().
as you can see in the video, he didnt call .exec() either.
sorry to have angered you but seriously i wanted another way of doing multi threading other than creating an extra class.

Comment: show us your main. I don't want to watch a whole video just to be able to answer your question.

Comment: In fact, show us your exact code. Because the code you show above should not even compile. And your "i created a QObject directly" is exactly where your basic problem lies. It's wrong. Don't try to attempt to "keep your project small". It's pointless and will not work. The Tutorial does it for a reason. Make sure you understand it first before you optimize anything.

Comment: @UmNyobe exactly the same as you mentioned above.

Comment: @UmNyobe basically i had dowork() with some huge code. i seggregated it into parts. so i thought of running these parts simultaneously so as to reduce the time as well as not make the gui freeze.
i am developing this program for solving simultaneous equations.
i observed that if i increased the no of variables the gui started to freeze. hence i decided to venture into multi threading.

Comment: I suggest you to watch the video again.

Comment: @UmNyobe yup i got my mistake.
he has app.exec() just below started() thats why his worked.
i will correct my mistake.
THANK YOU for your help.